# find a path to leaf equal to sum (not BST)

Tags: c, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a recursive function in C, which receives a root in a binary tree, and checks if a pathtoleaf equaling a given sum exists. For instance it receives the first node in the following tree:

> ```
>           1
>
>    2              3
>
> 5       10       4    20
>
>                             2
> ```

The following are examples of PathToLeaf:

- 1⟶2⟶10
- 2⟶5
- 20⟶2

The following are not PathToLeaf:

- 1⟶2
- 1⟶3⟶20

If a path exists, the function should return 1; if not it should return 0.

In this tree, if the sum=12, then the function should return 1, because of the path 2⟶10; if sum=4, then the function should return 0 because the only path (1⟶3) does not end in a leaf.

My big problem here is that I can only manage a function that checks a roottoleaf path.

Comment: Instead of a single sum, manage a set of sums. When you visit a node, (1) insert 0 to the current set and (2) add (as in arithmetic) the node's value to all elements of the set. Visit node's children with the new set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a function `roottoleaf(const BST *tree, int target)`, your `pathtoleaf(const BST *tree, int target)` function follows easily, does it not, using a suitable traversal of the tree?

```
int pathtoleaf(const BST *tree, int target)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return 0;
    else if (roottoleaf(tree, target))
        return 1;
    else if (pathtoleaf(tree->left, target))
        return 1;
    else if (pathtoleaf(tree->right, target))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

<sup>*2021-07-04: Updated to cover the case where `tree` is NULL.*</sup>

Comment: I need it as a recursive function and we are not working on a BST, the tree is unsorted

Comment: Call it an ST instead of a BST, or the B stands for Binary instead of Balanced.  It's a data type; its name doesn't matter.  The only thing I assume about it explicitly is that it contains members `left` and `right` which point to the next levels of the tree; there is absolutely no assumption about ordering or balance (just that the tree is binary; a node has at most two children).  You could have helped by showing what you'd got.  I've fixed its lack of recursiveness for you (fixing a bug too!); it needs to call itself for the child trees.

Comment: Code now tested; it works for me with my `roottoleaf()` function, which is 14 lines of code in my implementation (including the definition line, open and close braces).

Comment: It's nice code, but I need a function that doesn't use any external functions or external parameters.
here is what I cam up with:
`int isExistsPathToLeafForGivenSum(Tree * t, int sum){
 if(!t)
  return 0;
 if(t->left==NULL && t->right==NULL && t->value==sum)
  return 1;
 if(isExistsPathToLeafForGivenSum(t->left, sum)==1)
  return 1;
 else if(isExistsPathToLeafForGivenSum(t->right, sum)==1)
  return 1;
 else if(isExistsPathToLeafForGivenSum(t->left, sum-t->value)==1)
  return 1;
 else if(isExistsPathToLeafForGivenSum(t->right, sum-t->value)==1)
  return 1;
 else
  return 0;`

Comment: That looks like it should do it -- I've not tested your code.  If you have artifical constraints on your solution (such as 'only one function'), then state them in your question.  Outside of classrooms, that sort of constraint is not given; you can introduce functions when you see fit.  Inside classrooms, they want you to do things their way (not just a way that works).  We won't give answers that conform to artificial constraints if you don't tell us about the artificial constraints.